# What is the difference between Flight data recorder and performance data recorder

Tags: flight-data-recorder, flight-data-monitoring

Does Flight Data Recorder consists of performance data or both of them are recorded separately.
Do we also have flexibility when to start recording performance data like 
Records the initial conditions at the cruise ,climb/des intersection, or current conditions

Comment: Do you have any reference to a "performance data recorder"? Typically I've heard of Flight Data Recorder (FDR), Cockpit Voice Recorder (CVR), and Quick Access Recorder (QAR or QDR). Are you referring to the QAR?

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes I think QAR , I searched and found most of them use QAR to store performance data